# Chemical ions in latex, mathmode problem

Tags: macros

I'm trying to make a command that creates this line, with the II being correctly displayed [image]

I came up with this command, which works reasonably but it makes all the text afterwards italic like it is in mathmode.

```
\newcommand{\cair} {{
  Ca\,{\sc ii}~8542~\AA\:~}}
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

[image]

Comment: in older tex systems `\,` is only allowed in math mode and so switches to math. Add `\usepackage{amsmath}`, it should make it available for text too.

Comment: That worked! If you reply it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use amsmath package in order to display text on math enviroments.

No problem testing `Ca\,{\sc ii}~8542~\AA\:~` at overleaf.